# Exception calling fill with 1 argument ora-00933 sql command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, powershell, visual-studio-code, oracleclient

I'm having the above error message when I use powershell 5.1 in vscode to execute an oracle sql query.  I'm testing with a simple sql statement, but eventually it will be more complicated and the more complicated sql has at least 3 semicolons.

I'm looking at [remove semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066856/run-sql-file-containing-pl-sql-in-powershell) which said to remove semicolons, but I know this won't ultimately fix it because of my query.  I'm unclear what their other numbered solutions are saying to do.

I know sqlPlus isn't working for me for this because of a possible oracle driver issue.  Right now I'm trying the following:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data.OracleClient #at the top
...
$dataSource = "RMMPRDBLAH.company.net:1521/RMMPRDB"
$connectionString = "Data Source=$dataSource;User Id=$username;Password=$password;" 
$con = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($connectionString)    
$query = "select * from SEVERITY_TBL;" #Get-Content $sqlPath 
Write-Host "query: $query"
$con.open()
$dtSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$OracleAdapter = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter($query,$con)
[void]$OracleAdapter.Fill($dtSet)
```

Which works fine until .Fill, where I get the error message.  When I remove the semicolon from my simple query, it returns results, but like I said, ultimately I have a 200 line query to read from a file which has multiple semicolons, so I need to be able to have the semicolons.  I was having trouble trying to use ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter (maybe I need to do something other than Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data.OracleClient) for this, so I'm using OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter, which was fine until I found the semicolon issue.  How can I get this to work with the semicolon without sqlplus?  I have the Oracle Developer Tools for VS Code.

When I tried this method (which I'm not sure if this would help my semicolon issue)

```
$cmd = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand
```

It had this error, which I'm not sure how to fix:

> New-Object : Cannot find type
> [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand]: verify that the
> assembly containing this type is loaded.

Thanks!

Update:
I was able to simplify my long query so that it doesn't have more than one semicolon.  I see the issue with having multiples.  After I made this change, it Got past the fill.

Comment: A semicolon is a client-interpreted statement separator, not actually part of the SQL command. For a single statement just remove it. What does "the more complicated sql has at least 3 semicolons" mean - in that 200-line file do you have three SQL statements, which you will need to run with three separate calls; or is it actually a single PL/SQL block? If the file has multiple SQL statements then you will somehow need to read and split those, so they can be run individually.

Comment: I can't run and split the statements separately, because they are feeding info to each other.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me, unless you are talking about PL/SQL, or perhaps CTEs with functions. Please edit your question to include an example - not the whole 200-line file but something that shows what you mean.

Comment: FWIW you need [ODP.NET](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/InstallODP.htm#ODPNT150) to use the `OracleCommand` class

Comment: "I can't run and split the statements separately, because they are feeding info to each other" - please **edit your question**, supply all the information, and perhaps someone can help you.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - I was able to download the nuget package for odp.net, but wasn't sure how to get it into vscode, and bring into my powershell script

Comment: @Michele nupkg's are just zip files, you can unzip it with 7z or winrar (or PowerShell's `Expand-Archive` cmdlet if you rename the extension of the file to `.zip`). Unpack, then import into your current process with `Add-Type -Path .\path\to\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`

Comment: see update above

Comment: @AlexPoole - thanks.  I took another look at the query someone gave me, and see what you're saying.  I got rid of the content above the last section.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - thank you...I'll try installing it that way.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - I did this at vscode command line: Add-Type -Path "C:\Users\me\OneDrive \2021\temp endToEnd\oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core\oracle.manageddataaccess.core.3.21.50\lib\netstandard2.1\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"   and it says add-type unalbe to load one or more of the requested types.

Answer (score 0):

In .net if we are trying to  try parsing wrong type it can be issue.
ex:-if we trying to do  int.TryParse for long/Guid type values